# Replacing a string with count

Tags: bash, text, awk, replace, sed

I have a text file with 100k lines formatted like this:

```
something/a/blablaa.jpg 0
something/a/blablab.jpg 0
something/b/blablac.jpg 0
...
somethingelse/y/blablax.jpg 99
somethingelse/z/blablay.jpg 99
somethingelse/z/blablaz.jpg 99
```

I would like to replace the file names with a count starting from `1` up until `100000` starting from the first line until the last. This would be the result:

```
something/a/1.jpg 0
something/a/2.jpg 0
something/b/3.jpg 0
...
somethingelse/y/99997.jpg 99
somethingelse/z/99998.jpg 99
somethingelse/z/100000.jpg 99
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This awk (gnu awk) one-liner works for your example text:

```
awk '{$0=gensub("([^./]+)([.]jpg\\s)", ++i"\\2", "g",$0)}7' file
```

with your text:

```
kent$  awk '{$0=gensub("([^./]+)([.]jpg\\s)", ++i"\\2", "g",$0)}7' f 
something/a/1.jpg 0
something/a/2.jpg 0
something/b/3.jpg 0
somethingelse/y/4.jpg 99
somethingelse/z/5.jpg 99
somethingelse/z/6.jpg 99
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution with sed :

```
grep -n "." file | sed 's/\(.*\):\(.*\/\).*\(\..*\)/\2\1\3/g'

something/a/1.jpg 0
something/a/2.jpg 0
something/b/3.jpg 0
somethingelse/y/4.jpg 99
somethingelse/z/5.jpg 99
somethingelse/z/6.jpg 99
```

Another solution with awk :

```
cat -n file | awk '{gsub( "/[^/]*[.]" , "/"$1"." , $2 ); print $2, $3 }'

something/a/1.jpg 0
something/a/2.jpg 0
something/b/3.jpg 0
somethingelse/y/4.jpg 99
somethingelse/z/5.jpg 99
somethingelse/z/6.jpg 99
```

those solutions are available for all extentions ( .jpg ot others )

Comment: The sed solution only works for single digit line numbers at the moment.

Comment: Non, [^/]*  match an illimit numbre of  caracters differents of /

Comment: Yes, but I'm talking about the sed solution, which captures only one digit in the first capture group.

Comment: you're right, I forgot the *, I corrected it, thanks